# UsageDescription in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios10, xcode8

I tried to upload the iOS-10-update of our App to iTunes Connect. I am using Xcode 8 GM.

Unfortunately, after uploading, iTunes Connect sends a mail containing this:

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.

We support englisch, german an spanish, so in the folder of the app, there is a de.lproj, en.lproj and es.lproj-folder, each containing a InfoPlist.strings which does contain the given key:

```
"NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" = "my description…";
```

Any ideas, what is going wrong and how to check this? InfoPlist.strings has target Membership in the correct build-target and even in build-target of our app-extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must still include the `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key in the actual plist.
If you want, you could localize the entire plist file, rather than using InfoPlist.strings.

Comment: Ahh, that's it! Thank you!

Comment: For me I was getting errors with a blank key in the plist. I had to put some value there for Apple to accept the build.

Comment: You must enter a value to this key, without it Apple will not accept.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my apps, the solution shows you the itunnes connect via mail: review your info.plist and tries to add the following field:

```
  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
```

You can check here the permissions that now requires iOS 10 in its info.plist , here: https://blog.xamarin.com/new-ios-10-privacy-permission-settings/

This worked for me.

Comment: Nope, it's not exactly what the accepted answer says. The accepted answer doesn't mention the key to type into Xcode 8's Info.plist editor in a project's config: "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description". I kept trying to find it by typing in "Photo Library" or starting with "App". Hopefully those autocomplete fields can be fuzzy matching in the future.